Sister rafter ties or use independent joists for new ceiling
I have a ~22'x21' garage with 2x6 rafters and 2x6 rafter ties 24"OC. The 2x6 rafter ties span 21' with a 2x4 strongback and a couple of king posts connecting two sets of rafter ties and rafters.
I'd like to add a drywall ceiling with insulation, so the existing 2x6 rafter ties won't work. No storage in the attic is necessary. I believe the 10psf live load and 5psf dead load table is appropriate for this application, so IRC R802.5.1(1) suggests #2 2x10 24"OC would span 23-3 with L/240. The strongback between the existing rafter ties would need to be removed to make room for the larger joists.
My questions is if it would be better to sister the existing 2x6 rafter ties with these new 2x10s, or if I should place the 2x10s in between the rafter ties and connect them to the top plate with hurricane ties. In either case I would get the required 1.5" of bearing on the 2x4 top plates.
Placing the 2x10 joists independent of the rafter ties seems easier in so far as avoiding the gluing and screwing required to sister them. Additionally, it seems like the added weight of the strapping + ceiling would be placed entirely on the walls and not affect the existing roof structure. However, the 12"OC spacing between the old rafter ties and the new joists would complicate things like framing in attic access since one of the 2x10 joists would need to be cut with the attic access frame attached to neighboring 2x6 rafter ties.
If the 2x10s are sistered to the existing rafter ties, does the weight of the ceiling being transferred to those rafter ties require a different calculation than the 10psf live load/5psf dead load span table?
